# How to unscale a grouped data in R?

Tags: r, scale

I've got adataframe where i need to calculate the scaled values of Y, which i want to use fo forecasting whith glmnet or xgboost, and i' will need to unscale the result for every group i've got.

```
df <- data.frame(group = rep(c("gr1", "gr2"), each = 10), y = rnorm(20,2,8))

df <- df %>%  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(scaled_y = scale(y))
```

is thare a way to reconstruct y?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean you want to convert z scores back to their raw values?

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(5)
df <- data.frame(group = rep(c("gr1", "gr2"), each = 10), y = rnorm(20,2,8))

df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(scaled_y = scale(y),
         y_raw = mean(y) + (scaled_y * sd(y)))

# A tibble: 20 x 4
# Groups:   group [2]
   group        y scaled_y    y_raw
   <fct>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 gr1    -4.73     -0.800  -4.73  
 2 gr1    13.1       1.54   13.1   
 3 gr1    -8.04     -1.24   -8.04  
 4 gr1     2.56      0.156   2.56  
 5 gr1    15.7       1.88   15.7   
 6 gr1    -2.82     -0.550  -2.82  
 7 gr1    -1.78     -0.413  -1.78  
 8 gr1    -3.08     -0.584  -3.08  
 9 gr1    -0.286    -0.217  -0.286 
10 gr1     3.10      0.228   3.10  
11 gr2    11.8       1.88   11.8   
12 gr2    -4.41     -0.352  -4.41  
13 gr2    -6.64     -0.658  -6.64  
14 gr2     0.740     0.357   0.740 
15 gr2    -6.57     -0.649  -6.57  
16 gr2     0.888     0.378   0.888 
17 gr2    -2.78     -0.127  -2.78  
18 gr2   -15.5      -1.87  -15.5   
19 gr2     3.93      0.796   3.93  
20 gr2    -0.0748    0.245  -0.0748
```

Comment: That was easyer than i thought! Thank you kind person! And if i get it right, this mean and sd i'll be able to use to extratct vallues from the forecast of z-scores?